# How to handle 'ServiceUnavailable' exceptions when making multiple parallel calls to Cosmos DB with Azure SQL API?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have an API which is reading paged documents from cosmos and doing some processing on the paged documents(1000).

Manual Throughput : 4000 RUs
My Cosmos DB and App Server are in the same region (WEST US)

But for parallel calls (e.g 10) it is throwing below exception:

> {"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Error","Category":"***Repository","Message":"***.InflateResponse : Response status code does not indicate success: ServiceUnavailable (503); Substatus: 20002; ActivityId: 6ccf0716-d62c-4860-8f26-6503e42a3d89; Reason: (The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 3 endpoints across 1 regions. Please check for client resource starvation issues and verify connectivity between client and server. More info: [https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-service-unavailable\r\nActivityId](https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-service-unavailable/r/nActivityId):

Increasing the RUs to 10k supports only 20 parallel calls.
But i don't think increasing RUs is a solution to this problem.

Can someone please suggest?

I tried bringing both app server and db in the same region with increased RUs, it improved but not as expected.

Comment: Increasing RU/s will do nothing here. The error message is telling you the issue is client side. The answer to your question is likely in the error message. Follow the link here, then check the substatus code in your response. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-service-unavailable